# Inequality about absolute value and tolerance, as applied to real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, absolute-value

It seems that the following statement about absolute value inequalities are very useful in real analysis.  I can prove it using case analysis, but would expect a more direct proof, such as via the triangle inequality.  Is there a direct proof?  Is my proof below the best? Is there a name for this statement?

If $a$ is within $e$ of $b$, then $a > b-e$ and $a < b+e$.  More formally, $|a-b|<e \implies b-e < a < b+e$.

Proof: $e$ is clearly greater than $0$.  If $a > b$, then $a > b-e$.  If $a < b$, then $-(a-b)=b-a < e$, so $a > b-e$.  A similar argument follows for the other half of the inequality.  QED.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks.  Fixed.

Comment: Use that $|u| \lt v \iff -v \lt u \lt v$.